# How to update a data control on a page using the signalr?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I'm using visual studio 2012 ultimate and I keep searching about using asp.net signalr for realtime push of data
into the webforms. All I've got are about chat applications and moving an object in the webpage in realtime.
But I could hardly figure out how to apply their codes they used if I want to update a page with a data control
on it like (gridview or listview) that is being binded with my database through sqldatasource control.
Please give me a video tutorials or any articles that demontrates how to update a page using the signalr with data control on it that is binded
with the database to display the data.

Thanks...

As of this moment this is what I've tried to come up
my class file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for RefreshHub
/// </summary>
namespace mytestSignalR
{
    [HubName("refresh")]
    public class RefreshHub : Hub
    {
        string filename;

        [HubMethodName("update")]
        public void UpdatePage()
        {

            string conn = @"Server=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Windblow.mdf";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
            SqlDataReader dr;

            connection.Open();
            // string sql = "INSERT INTO [ProfileTab]([ID],[Name],[Address],[Age],[Occupation],[Nationality]) Values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "' ) ";
            string sql = "Select * From [ImageTab] ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                filename = dr.GetString(0);

            }
            dr.Close();
            connection.Close();

            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<RefreshHub>();
            context.Clients.All.Databind(filename);
        }


    }
}
```

JS codes on page to update:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4-vsdoc.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" >

        $(function () {

            var page = $.connection.refreshHub;

            // $lview = $("#ListView1");
            page.client.databind = function (filename) {
                //  $lview = $("#ListView1");
                $("#ListView1").bind(filename);
                // $lview.bind(filename);
            };
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                page.server.updatePage();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

but still got a runtime error when running. It says
***Line: 21
Error: Unable to get property 'refreshHub' of undefined or null reference***

It highlights on this line of code `var page = $.connection.refreshHub;`
Where did I go wrong? What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried..

Comment: Why do you have both jquery and jquery.min, signalr, and signalr.min? you should use only one of each (and no .vsdoc also). Other thing, is this "~/signalr/hubs" correct? No ".js" file?

Comment: Now I got no more any runtime error at all after I change the script reference to <script src="signalr/hubs"></script> but nothing happens on my page. The listview won't update unless you reload the browser. Any thoughts about what's wrong either my jquery codes or my RefreshHub.cs?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems you've never coded client side yet.

So, here's a tip: before trying to use SignalR, try to learn a lot of javascript, and if you can, jQuery as well.

You won't be able to use SignalR to bind a server control, like you are used to. You'll need to turn the data you grap from your database to a JSON string, and then pass this information to the webform.

So, you'll take this information and turn this JSON string in a Javascript object, and dynamically create the HTML content you want to.

A GridView Control, for example, is nothing more than a HTML "table" tag.

So, you'll need to take this object, loop into it to create all the children elements of this table. It'll be much easier to use jQuery for that.

Some code examples:

HTML:

```
<button id="btnGridPopulator">Bind grid</button>

<table id="myClientGridView">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="100px" />
        <col width="200px" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnGridPopulator").click(bindGrid);
});

function bindGrid() {
    // here I'll simulate a message, as if it came from your SignalR
    onmessage('[{"id":0,"title":"My videos"},{"id":1,"title":"My images"},{"id":2,"title":"My documents"}]');
}

function onmessage(msg)
{
    var arr = JSON.parse(msg);

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        $("#myClientGridView").append("<tr><td>" + arr[i].id + "</td><td>" + arr[i].title + "</td></tr>");
    }
}
```

[Fiddle with a example of what you'll need to do](http://jsfiddle.net/5VetG/)

Comment: What about if I don't have a click event on that page because that page just to show the data but the page where you upload the data came from the other webform. Please see my updated post..Thanks

Comment: I just want to auto-update the listview control after the data has been uploaded from the other webform.

Answer (score 0):

change your code, like this

```
// var page = $.connection.refreshHub;
var page = $.connection.refresh;
```

and

```
// page.server.updatePage();
page.server.update();
```

because you change class name and method name, by HubName attribute and HubMethodName attribute

Comment: I also tried that many times but still getting the same runtime error. Now I tried it again and its giving me Line: 21
Error: Unable to get property 'refresh' of undefined or null reference and I also tried to change it to page.server.update(); and no effects as well

Comment: Other messages don't appear in console of the browser? Are you successful to load signalr/hubs?

Comment: No,there's no other messages in the console of the browser but I'm not sure if the signalr has loaded or not. How do I determine this one?

Comment: Are you created Owin Startup class?

Comment: No Do I need it? How do I construct it?

Comment: refer to [Tutorial: Getting Started with SignalR 2.0](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20)

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SignalRdatabind;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;

namespace SignalRdatabind.Hub
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}

Comment: I tried this one but I got error when I build and says Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Owin' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
Error 3 The type or namespace name 'IAppBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you need install Microsoft.Owin and Microsoft.Owin.Security

Comment: After adding a startup class I encoounter these runtime error when running the apps. Here the following runtime errors that will display on the page

Comment: No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.

Comment: The discovered startup type 'SignalRdatabind.Startup, SignalRdatabind, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' conflicts with the type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Startup, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Remove or rename one of the types, or reference the desired type directly.

Comment: To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.

Comment: Yes I took care of that runtime error but this runtime error is still coming back  **Line: 21 Error: Unable to get property 'refreshHub' of undefined or null reference** Are you sure that the only mistakes on my RefreshHub.cs file are about the hubname and the hubmethodname as you mentioned earlier because I already tried changing both but still getting same error.

Comment: try changing to "mytestSignalR" the namespace of Startup class

Comment: Yes I took care of that runtime error but this runtime error is still coming back Line: 21 Error: Unable to get property 'refreshHub' of undefined or null reference Are you sure that the only mistakes on my RefreshHub.cs file are about the hubname and the hubmethodname as you mentioned earlier because I already tried changing both but still getting same error.

Comment: Why its saying undefined or null reference pointing on my RefreshHub.cs

Comment: If you want to use "refreshHub" as HubName, you must delete HubName attribute. Otherwise you must use "refresh" as HubName. Did you try "$.connection.refresh" after you created startup class and resolved sever side runtime error?

Comment: Yes I did as I've already mentioned earlier and I also tried page.server.update(); but the same error is coming in.

Comment: where is RefreshHub.cs on project tree?

Comment: The RefreshHub.cs is my class file which is located in one of my server folder named 'Hub'.

Comment: Did you not find any missing codes on my RefreshHub.cs?

Comment: please change folder name to "Hubs", and change namespace of RefreshHub to "mytestSignalR.Hubs".

Comment: I can't find other problem on RefreshHub.cs.

Comment: project setting or path of signalr/hubs might be problem.

Comment: same thing its still giving the same error message. I think I got the right path for the signalR <script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>. And project setting? What should be change on my settings here on my project?

Comment: take note that I'm using a listview control which is directly binded by the sqldatasource to display the data from database. If you take a look do I need to use a DataTable object for this to set on my string filename that was declared?

Comment: Your error is that refreshHub can not be found. It is defined in the signal/hubs. Please check the contents of signalr/hubs using the development tools or web inspector in the browser

Comment: As I've check the contents of the signalr/hubs in the developers tool it shows these following messages:

Comment: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Things you can try:
Create the content on the Web server.
Review the browser URL.
Check the failed request tracing log and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information, click here.

Comment: I notice I run my project through IIS Express, does this matter?How do I change it back to ASP.Net Development Server?

Comment: I run my project through IIS Express too. it's working. I think the path of signalr/hub is wrong. Place of it varies depending on the project configuration.

Comment: I notice on my Scripts folder in my server I don't have signalr/hubs. I only got the following js files after I downloaded the signalr by nuget:

Comment: <script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script  src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script  src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script  src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script  src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: signalr/hubs will be created dynamically at run-time.

Comment: Is it possible to resolve this by uninstalling the existing signalr package and reinstall it by nugetz?

Comment: run this command in the Package Manager Console.  
    > uninstall-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR  
    > install-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

Comment: After I uninstall and reinstall the signalr package the runtime error is now pointing my javascript code it hightlights on this part:

Comment: page.client.databind = function (filename) {
                //  $lview = $("#ListView1");
               
                $("#ListView1").bind(filename);
                // $lview.bind(filename);
            };

Comment: and the runtime error displays on the javascript console of the developers tools displays like this: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8761/~/signalr/hubs
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined PhotoGallery.aspx:22
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: I have a doubt on my jquery codes since I'm not sure if call the listview correctly to bind the data.Any suggestions?

Comment: please try change your JS code <script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script> to <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

Comment: Now I got no more any runtime error at all after I change the script reference to <script src="signalr/hubs"></script> but nothing happens on my page. The listview won't update unless you reload the browser. Any thoughts about what's wrong either my jquery codes or my RefreshHub.cs?

Comment: it's probably jquery code. bind in jquery is "Attach a handler to an event for the elements.", it's not data binding

Comment: refer to [here](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1726785.aspx?How+to+bind+Gridview+Repater+Listview+from+the+client+side)

Comment: My listview control is directly binded with the SqlDataSource control to the database to display the data. There's no any event on this page because this page will display the data immediately once it is loaded since it is binded with the SqlDatasource directly. That's why I want this page to automatically update once there's a data being uploaded from the other web form.